# Book in which a kid finds out his dad is a fairy

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about when a kid finds out his dad is a fairy, maybe some important political figure. So he goes to Fairyland. Apparently, in Fairyland, no one wears clothes.

Comment: "So he goes to Fairyland." Is this a common, known, easy to get to place?

Comment: Doesn't seem too broad, please give 2-3 examples of books with a fairy realm with naked people and MC's dad being a fairy if you think it is.

Comment: @Jenayah - It's terse but does contain some unique details

Comment: @Valorum yep, hence my Leave Open vote. Should've clarified that the earlier comment was addressed to close voters

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Magicalamity](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13572812-magicalamity) by Kate Saunders?

> Tom is in shock. He's just discovered that his dad is an escaped fairy
>   on the run. And that he must trust his life to three dangerous fairy
>   godmothers he's never met. Two of them are hardened criminals, and one
>   falls out of the window when she tries to fly . . .
>
> Will their mad magic be enough to help Tom rescue his dad from the
>   clutches of some killer fairies?

Comment: In support of the 'Magicalamity' answer I have found this quote:- No sexual content, but it is mentioned quite a few times that the fairies have nude balls and sometimes go around nude. No body parts described in any kind of detail, but this may bother some kids and parents

Comment: @DannyMcG - I've heard that the fairy's nude balls are legendary

Comment: Haha, I thought of that as soon as I'd posted the comment, it was a....."what did I just write?"

Comment: @DannyMcG Yep, definitely a double take on that one. The first thing I pictured was a very unsightly pair of shorts.

Comment: @MishaR - Gunther's gonna help you out with that one; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MDLIsJWQe8

Comment: Huh. With the portmanteau title, I was half expecting this to be part of the *Paranormalcy* series (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7719245-paranormalcy), which has a similar twist of learning that a character's parent is a fairy.